# get Page-scoped-id from App-scoped-id

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger

I am trying to get the Page-scoped-id using a get request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{app-scoped-id}?fields=page_scoped_id
```

according to Facebook Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

But I receive this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter page is required",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "GYI1b2zz4fL"
  }
}
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I submitted a bug on Facebook and actually it is a bug. They are working to fix it. I'll keep updated the question

Comment: The app has to be linked to a page for it to work. Is that the case here?

Comment: yes, my page is subscribed to my app.

Comment: What type of access token are you using?

Comment: a page access token

Comment: Page access tokens are also app-specific, perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't work neither with user access token. But the app has to be linked to a page, so if the page access token is specific for an app I don't see the issue